# Convert footnotes references into Harvard Referencing System in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have doc with a lot of footnotes but now I have to convert this references into Harvard Referencing System.

Example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<sup>1</sup>. Sed ac purus a sem sagittis dignissim.
>   ...
>   <sup>1</sup> Curabitur at sapien feugiat

into:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit [Curabitur at sapien feugiat]. Sed ac purus a sem sagittis dignissim.

Can anyone help me with this?

**EDIT:**
I have Office 2007 and 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.biblesupport.com/topic/1258-converting-footnotes-to-in-line-citations-word-macro/) Macro does exactly what you want. Here's how to use it (with screenshots at the bottom)

**Note: This Macro disables undo at the end of each footnote move, so keep a backup of your document BEFORE you do anything, in case it doesn't do exactly what you want!! You can re-enable undo by removing the 3rd to last and 4th to last lines, but I don't recommend it if you have a very large document!!**

To set this up in Office 2013 (from the same link as above, I've edited it for Office 2013):

1) Press Alt+F11

2) At the top in the menu bar, click Insert>Module

3) In the main window copy and paste the below macro

4) In the properties window, rename the module to any name you want and the name on the left window if you change the modules name.

5) Save Normal and Close the editor

6) Press Alt+F8, choose the macro, and press Run

Macro (I've edited so it works like in your example). You can change the colour code to anything you want - you want the [decimal value for colour](http://www.mathsisfun.com/hexadecimal-decimal-colors.html) - it's black by default:

```
Sub foot2inline()
Dim oFeets As Footnotes
Dim oFoot As Footnote
Dim oRange As Range
Dim szFootNoteText As String

' Grabs the collection of FootNotes
Set oFeets = Word.ActiveDocument.Footnotes

' Iterates through each footnote
For Each oFoot In oFeets      

    szFootNoteText = oFoot.Range.Text

    'Start search from beginning of document
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^f" ' Looks for all footnotes
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute
    ' Delete the footnote
    oFoot.Delete

    'Insert the footnote text
    'Here you do whatever format tickles your fancy
    'The only thing you need to keep is the speech marks and 'szFootNotetext'
    'Make sure anything you want to surround the citations is inside speech marks.
    'For example = " (" + szFootNoteText + ") "
    Selection.Text = " [" + szFootNoteText + "] "

    'CHANGE COLOR HERE. Color code is below.
    Selection.Font.Color = 0

    'Disables undo to save memory on very large documents.
    ActiveDocument.UndoClear
Next
End Sub
```

Screenshots:

Setting up the Macro: [image]
Your document with footnotes: [image]
Using the macro: [image]
Your document with your referencing system: [image]

Answer (score 1):

It works like a charm.
I changed a bit your macro so this adds content of footnote into bibliography sources (as a tittle) and insert citation in place of footnote reference.

maybe someone will use this:

```
Sub foot2inline()
Dim oFeets As Footnotes
Dim oFoot As Footnote
Dim oRange As Range
Dim szFootNoteText As String

' Grabs the collection of FootNotes
Set oFeets = Word.ActiveDocument.Footnotes
Dim tagNumber As Integer
tagNumber = 1
' Iterates through each footnote
For Each oFoot In oFeets

    szFootNoteText = oFoot.Range.Text

    'Start search from beginning of document
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^f" ' Looks for all footnotes
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute
    ' Delete the footnote
    oFoot.Delete

    'Insert the footnote text
    'Here you do whatever format tickles your fancy
    'The only thing you need to keep is the speech marks and 'szFootNotetext'
    'Make sure anything you want to surround the citations is inside speech marks.
    'For example = " (" + szFootNoteText + ") "

    Dim tag As String
    tag = "Tag" + CStr(tagNumber)

    Selection.Fields.Add Selection.Range, _
            wdFieldCitation, tag

    Dim strXml As String
    strXml = _
        "<b:Source xmlns:b=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/" & _
        "office/word/2004/10/bibliography""><b:Tag>" & tag & "</b:Tag>" & _
        "<b:SourceType>Book</b:SourceType><b:Author><b:Author>" & _
        "<b:NameList><b:Person><b:Last>LastName</b:Last>" & _
        "<b:First>FirstName</b:First></b:Person></b:NameList></b:Author>" & _
        "</b:Author><b:Title>" & szFootNoteText & "</b:Title>" & _
        "<b:Year>1996</b:Year><b:City>City</b:City>" & _
        "<b:Publisher>Publisher</b:Publisher>" & _
        "</b:Source>"

    ActiveDocument.Bibliography.Sources.Add (strXml)

    'CHANGE COLOR HERE. Color code is below.
    Selection.Font.Color = 0

    'Disables undo to save memory on very large documents.
    ActiveDocument.UndoClear
    tagNumber = tagNumber + 1
Next
End Sub
```